# jquery backstretch white background on load in FF

Tags: jquery, jquery-backstretch

I am working on a demo for a site and when I load or refresh the page in FF (mac), it looks like the background from the left column takes up the entire page until you resize the browser or scroll the mouse.

Doesn't seem to happen in Chrome (mac). Not too sure if it's something in my CSS or if it's something with FF.
Also, doesn't seem to happen when I don't use the gallery for the background images.

Here's a link to my demo:

http://review.boostmktg.com/niven/

Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is working fine for me.  Firefox 17.0.1 on Mac 10.7.5

Comment: Interesting. Maybe it's just me then? I'm on FF 17.0.1 and on Lion 10.7.5  as well. I'll try another Mac and see if that has any issues.

Comment: Yeah, I just tested it on a co-worker's Mac who's running the same thing and it shows up fine with out the display of the white BG on page load. Meh, maybe I just need to reboot...